# Core-SVP Hardness of Kyber

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, security-definition, kyber, kem

This question is with reference to the python file `model_BKZ.py` provided in the GitHub repository https://github.com/pq-crystals/security-estimates/blob/master/model_BKZ.py

In this file, there is function called `construct_BKZ_shape`. I am not able to understand what it is doing. I have read BKZ algorithm from [this paper](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2011/70730001/70730001.pdf) and the [YouTube lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EapIVDlhvQU) by Prof. Damien Stehlé.

I am not able to link the mathematical theory I read through these sources with the code provided here. Can somebody please explain this code from the mathematical point of view? What we are trying to do through this code?

```
def construct_BKZ_shape(q, nq, n1, b):
    """ Simulate the (log) shape of a basis after the reduction of
        a [q ... q, 1 ... 1] shape after BKZ-b reduction (nq many q's, n1 many 1's)
        This is implemented by constructing a longer shape and looking
        for the subshape with the right volume. Also outputs the index of the
        first vector <q, and the last >q.

        # Note: this implentation takes O(n). It is possible to output
        # a compressed description of the shape in time O(1), but it is much
        # more prone to making mistakes

    """
    d = nq+n1
    if b==0:
        L = nq*[log(q)] + n1*[0]
        return (nq, nq, L)


    slope = -2 * log(delta_BKZ(b))
    lq = log(q)
    B = int(floor(log(q) / - slope))    # Number of vectors in the sloppy region
    L = nq*[log(q)] + [lq + i * slope for i in range(1, B+1)] + n1*[0]

    x = 0
    lv = sum (L[:d])
    glv = nq*lq                     # Goal log volume

    while lv > glv:                 # While the current volume exceeeds goal volume, slide the window to the right
        lv -= L[x]
        lv += L[x+d]
        x += 1

    assert x <= B                   # Sanity check that we have not gone too far

    L = L[x:x+d]
    a = max(0, nq - x)             # The length of the [q, ... q] sequence
    B = min(B, d - a)              # The length of the GSA sequence

    diff = glv - lv
    assert abs(diff) < lq               # Sanity check the volume, up to the discretness of index error
    for i in range(a, a+B):        # Small shift of the GSA sequence to equiliBrate volume
        L[i] += diff / B
    lv = sum(L)
    assert abs(lv/glv - 1) < 1e-6        # Sanity check the volume

    return (a, a + B, L)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is attempting to model the size of the logarithms of the norms of the Gram-Schmidt vectors associated with a BKZ reduced basis under the Geometric Series Assumption where before reduction the basis was of the form

$$\begin{bmatrix}A & I_{n_1}\\ qI_{n_q} & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

In lattice basis reduction, for a basis $\mathbf b_1,\ldots, \mathbf b_d$ we typically also keep track of its [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) $\mathbf b^*_1,\ldots,\mathbf b^*_d$. Reduction processes are meant to produce bases where the Gram-Schmidt vectors do not become too small in norm. An empirical observation (see the remarks at the end of section 2 of the Chen and Nguyen paper) is the "Geometric Series Assumption" that reduction processes such as LLL or BKZ tend to produce reduced bases where the norms of the $\mathbf b^*_i$ decrease as an approximate geometric progression: $|\mathbf b^*_i|\approx \delta^{i-1}|\mathbf b^*_1|$ for some $\delta<1$ dependent on the block size (related to the `delta_BKZ(b)` in the code). This observation is subject to the limitation that Gram-Schmidt norms should not be bigger than the biggest initial vector, nor smaller than 1 for lattices with integer entries. If we plot the logarithm of the G-S norms against the index, the GSA means that we should see an approximate piecewise linear plot that can take one of the following shapes:

[image: Possible log G-S norm shapes]

The exact shape and parameters are determined by the slope (which is $\log\delta$) and the area beneath the plot (which is the log of the determinant of the lattice).

In the code, the exact shape is found by notionally constructing a piecewise linear plot of $n_q+B+n_1$ width where $B$ is the width of the base of right-angled triangle with height $\log q$ and hypotenuse with slope $\delta$. They then look for a window of width $d=n_q+n_1$ of this plot where the area within the window and beneath the plot is equal to the log of the determinant of the lattice. This is the desired shape.

Here's a legend for some of the variable names in terms of the above description

| Variable | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `d` | $d$ the dimension of the lattice |
| `nq` | $n_q$ the number of columns in the $qI$ sub matrix |
| `n1` | $n_1$ the number of columns in the $I$ sub matrix |
| `slope` | $\log\delta$ the notional slope of the diagonal part of the plot |
| `lq` | $\log q$ the upper bound for the size of the log of the Gram-Schmidt norms |
| `B` | $B$ the width of a sloped region descending from $\log q$ to 0 with slope $\log \delta$ |
| `L` | A list of "$y$-values" for the wide plot of width $n_q+B+n_1$ |
| `x` | The offset into the wide plot of our window |
| `lv` | The area beneath the plot in our current window |
| `glv` | The target area which is the log of the determinant of our lattice (which is $n_q\log q$) |

Because the plot is more accurately described as a histogram with the window sliding one unit at a time, a final adjustment of the sloped region is required to make the areas match. This is the meaning of the lines beginning `diff = glv - lv`  and finishing `assert abs...`

Finally note this code does not behave correctly for the last shape illustrated (this may be due to restriction of the values of $b$, $n_q$ and $n_1$ under consideration). I would advise against directly reusing this for fully general lattice modelling. As the programmer notes, there are quicker computations of the shape, but it is easy to get things wrong.